# In dwr.xml how to exclude some class or classes from global filter?

Tags: filter, dwr

There is possibility to make global filter in [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) (direct web remoting). For example if you need to check if user is logged in, you write it in one place - in filter, that is indicated it in **dwr.xml** as global filter:

```
<allow>
  ....
  <filter class="mypackage.MyFilterClass"/>
  ....
</allow>
```

But there are classes that user is allowed without authentication, for example authentication class itself. I want to know how to indicate in global filter tag what class or classes I want not to be filtered (excluded)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the exceptional class as parameter to your filter. In your filter you can check against this parameter and do noop for this class.

```
<filter class="org.mypackage.MyFilter">
  <param name="excluded" value="org.mypackage.MyClass"/>
</filter>
```